# Correctly build a WAV header and produce some sounds via WaveOut API

Tags: winapi

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? All functions return Success. The callback function is called for OPEN and CLOSE. But I can't hear any sound from my sound card.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

typedef size_t herz_t;
typedef float  progress_t;

class audio32_t 

      { public :      audio32_t();
        virtual      ~audio32_t();

        void          DatasRefresh(const herz_t &_carrier, const progress_t &_level)

                      { audio32_t::_carrier(_carrier, _level, this->_header);

                        ::waveOutWrite(this->_apiout, &this->_header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
                      }

        private :

        HANDLE        _apiclock;
        HWAVEOUT      _apiout;
        WAVEHDR       _header;

        static
        WAVEFORMATEX  _w32style;

        static
        void          _carrier(const herz_t &, const progress_t &, WAVEHDR &);
        static
        void          _w32proc(HWAVEOUT, UINT, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);
      };

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

WAVEFORMATEX audio32_t::_w32style;

audio32_t::audio32_t() : _apiclock(0),
                         _apiout(0),
                         _header()

                         { audio32_t::_w32style.wFormatTag      = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
                           audio32_t::_w32style.nChannels       = 2;
                           audio32_t::_w32style.nSamplesPerSec  = 44100;
                           audio32_t::_w32style.wBitsPerSample  = audio32_t::_w32style.nChannels * 8;
                           audio32_t::_w32style.cbSize          = 0;

                           audio32_t::_w32style.nBlockAlign     = static_cast<byte_t>(   audio32_t::_w32style.nChannels
                                                                                                    * (audio32_t::_w32style.wBitsPerSample
                                                                                                       / 8
                                                                                                      )
                                                                                                  );

                                        audio32_t::_w32style.nAvgBytesPerSec = audio32_t::_w32style.nSamplesPerSec
                                                                             * audio32_t::_w32style.nBlockAlign;

                                        this->_header.dwBufferLength  = 0;
                                        this->_header.lpData          = 0;
                                        this->_header.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
                                        this->_header.dwUser          = 0;
                                        this->_header.dwFlags         = WHDR_BEGINLOOP | WHDR_ENDLOOP;
                                        this->_header.dwLoops         = 0xFFFF;
                                        this->_header.lpNext          = NULL;
                                        this->_header.reserved        = 0;

                                        this->_header.dwBufferLength  = audio32_t::_w32style.nAvgBytesPerSec;
                                        this->_header.lpData          = ::new char[this->_header.dwBufferLength * 2];

                                        ::waveOutOpen( &this->_apiout, WAVE_MAPPER,
                                                       &audio32_t::_w32style,
                                                       reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(&audio32_t::_w32proc),
                                                       reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(this),

                                                       CALLBACK_FUNCTION
                                                     );
                                      }

audio32_t::~audio32_t() { ::waveOutClose(this->_apiout); }

void audio32_t::_carrier(const herz_t &_herz, const progress_t &_lvl, WAVEHDR &_header)

     { const
       size_t _half  = (_header.dwBufferLength / 2);
       const
       double _w     = 2.0 * M_PI * double(_herz) / double(audio32_t::_w32style.nSamplesPerSec);

       for(size_t _x = 0; _x < _header.dwBufferLength; _x += 2)
          { const
            double _byte = ::sin(double(_x) * _w);

            if(_x > _half)
              { _header.lpData[_x + 0] = char((128.0 + 0.0)   * _lvl  / 100.0f);
                _header.lpData[_x + 1] = char((128.0 + _byte) * _lvl  / 100.0f);
              }
            else
              { _header.lpData[_x + 0] = char((128.0 + _byte) * _lvl  / 100.0f);
                _header.lpData[_x + 1] = char((128.0 + 0.0)   * _lvl  / 100.0f);
              }
          }
     }

void audio32_t::_w32proc(HWAVEOUT _out, UINT _request, DWORD _, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2)

     { audio32_t *_this = (audio32_t *)_;

       switch(_request)
             { case MM_WOM_OPEN  : { ::waveOutPrepareHeader(_this->_apiout, &_this->_header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
                                     ::waveOutWrite(_this->_apiout, &_this->_header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

                                     break;
                                   }

               case WOM_DONE  : { //_this->Refresh();

                                  break;
                                }

               case MM_WOM_CLOSE : { ::waveOutReset(_this->_apiout);
                                     ::waveOutUnprepareHeader(_this->_apiout, &_this->_header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

                                     if(_this->_header.lpData != 0)
                                       { ::delete [] reinterpret_cast<byte_t *>(_this->_header.lpData);

                                         _this->_header.lpData = 0;
                                       }

                                     break;
                                   }

               case WIM_DATA     : { break; }

               default           : { break; }
             }
     }

#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

void main()

     { audio32_t _audio("mmsystem");

        _audio.DatasRefresh(0, 0);

        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 25);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "+";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 50);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "+";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 75);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "+";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 100); ::Sleep(500);    cout << "=";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 75);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "-";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 50);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "-";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200, 25);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "-";
        _audio.DatasRefresh(1200,  0);  ::Sleep(500);    cout << "0";

        ::cout << ::endl << "ok";
        ::getch();
      }
```

When I run the program from C++Builder6, I can see the Wave Entry on the Volume Mixer of Windows, but no sound is played.

The class `audio32_t` is just a wrapper for the WaveOut API. Just a call to `DatasRefresh(...)` should change the carrier.

I'm also wondering why `WOM_DONE` is not fired, as `MM_WOM_OPEN` and `MM_WOM_CLOSE` are effectively fired.

Comment: It seems that you couldn't open the file or load an audio block? I suggest you could refer to the sample:https://gist.github.com/seungin/4779216eada24a5077ca1c5e857239ce

Comment: I will explore that code and come back later....thanks foe the link

Answer (score 0):

For sure : it was so simple... WHDR_DONE has to be set in dwflags...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).